# Can I use z-scores in independent samples T-test?

Tags: t-test, standardization, z-score

I have two datasets from different groups. I am interested in comparing the difference of an attitudinal outcome between the groups. However, the outcomes were measured on different scales so I had to standardize them into z-scores before making the comparison.

I wonder is it still valid to use the z-scores in the t-test given that both scales now have zero mean and unit standard deviation?